# Combine two sklearn pipelines into one

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a text preprocessing Pipeline:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
  ('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
  ('chi2score', SelectKBest(chi2, k=1000)),
  ('tfidf_transformer', TfidfTransformer(norm='l2', use_idf=True)),
])
```

and I want to perform cross validation **on a pipeline** with multiple estimators. This is a solution that is working, but honestly I don't really like it. There should be a better way to do it. Maybe somehow convert the Pipeline to a transformer?

```
pipe_nb = Pipeline([*pipe.steps, ('naive_bayes', MultinomialNB())])
```

That's an approach that I perceive as an ideal one, but unfortunately it does not merge steps into new pipeline and causes issues.

```
pipe_nb = make_pipeline(
  pipe, 
  MultinomialNB()
)
```

How to merge two pipelines into one, in a nice pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

Why do not simply append a new step into `pipe.steps` rather than to recreate a new one?

```
pipe.steps.append(('naive_bayes', MultinomialNB()))
print(pipe)

# Output
Pipeline(steps=[('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
                ('chi2score', SelectKBest(k=1000, score_func=1)),
                ('tfidf_transformer', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('naive_bayes', MultinomialNB())])
```

Or:

```
# Don't forget the *
pipe2 = make_pipeline(*pipe, MultinomialNB())
print(pipe2)

# Output
Pipeline(steps=[('countvectorizer', CountVectorizer()),
                ('selectkbest', SelectKBest(k=1000, score_func=1)),
                ('tfidftransformer', TfidfTransformer()),
                ('multinomialnb', MultinomialNB())])
```

Comment: Second step is what is in the question description, but you that's a great point - I forgot the star unpacking! I might potentially go with this solution. Regarding appending - I want to have the preprocessing pipe as separate, so it isn't an acceptable solution.

Comment: So what's wrong with your solution with `make_pipeline`?

Comment: I didn't use the star expression which didn't unpack transformers

Comment: I found out another issue. make_pipeline changes names of the steps